# Siri Intent request access token OAUTH token

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am integrating Custom Siri Shortcuts in my app, If the user execute that shortcut, I am making api call to find the results that SIRI can respond to the user.

These are the workflows

> While making, api call we need to refresh the access token, that token
> we need to pass in the api header for authentication purpose
>
> We rely on the OAuth framework (POD dependency) that is a part of Main
> app to get access token

My Question is, is it possible to get the access token from the main app or do I need to include OAuth framework as a POD dependency in Siri Extension. what is the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the access token through UserDefaults then you can pass the token with help of App Groups. Like:

`UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.company")!.bool(forKey: "data")`

Otherwise,

You can make a separate class to request the access token and make the class to target to both Siri and main app. Like:

[image]